# MVC.NET Bundling Web-App scripts and styles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've setup my IIS, with a "Shell" as the Root of the website, and everything else as web-app under shell.

I have a web-app containing all my styles/scripts etc.
I'm trying to setup the Bundles but I'm hitting a brick wall here. any help is much appreciated:
In `BundleConfig.cs` of my main "Shell" website, I'm trying to bundle things up like so:

```
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Kendo/Scripts/kendoJS").Include(
         "~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/{version}/jquery.min.js"
        ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/{version}/kendo.all.min.js"
        ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/{version}/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
        ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/kendo.modernizr.custom.js"
    ));
}
```

//EDIT:

Following doesn't seem to be working, as I don't see the scripts being included (Note, ~/Kendo/ is pointing to a web-application under the main "shell" website). I can't post an image given i'm all new and all. I would've loved to show you my IIS setup:

BundleConfig.cs:
{

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Kendo/Scripts/kendoJS").Include(
     "~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
    ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.all.min.js"
    ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
    ,"~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/kendo.modernizr.custom.js"
    ));
```

}

_layout.cshtml:
{

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo/Scripts/kendoJS")

}

Comment: And.. what's the problem?

Comment: First I was getting the "Directory not found" error. So for now, I've modified /{version}/ to the actual version numbers. So in my BundleConfig.cs file, I have: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Kendo/Scripts/kendoJS").Include("~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")); now in my _layout.cshtml file, I'm referencing the bundle by: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo/Scripts/kendoJS"); however, the scripts are not being included

Comment: Well one unrelated issue - Mondernizr should not be in your bundle. That should be its own minified file in your `head`. The other scripts should be before the `</body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `{version}` in place of folder name.

Take a look this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

**Update**

If Kendo is your project name and it's not a folder, you don't need to add that in the 
path. Just like below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendoJS").Include(
              "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery-{version}.js"
));
```

If Kendo is a folder name, the path should be like below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendoJS").Include(
              "~/Kendo/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery-{version}.js"
));
```

Comment: thanks for the correction; I modified the {version} for now... i'll find a work around. I still don't seem to get the scripts included properly, after replacing the {version} though (it did get rid of the "directory not found" error though)

Comment: Try to change the ScriptBundle path, then test that again.

Comment: all right, Kendo is a 3rd party mvc.net addin. when I created the kendo project, it put the "jquery.js" script under the root folder of Scripts while all other kendo scripts are under the "versioned" section. As per your suggestion, I needed to look closer. It's resolved. thank you!!